# Runtime communication Fortran - Python

Tags: python, cmake, fortran

I am currently using a multi-physics solver written in Fortran. Now, I would like to substitute a module of it with a Python counterpart, thus requesting to this Python script some parameters which are then passed to Fortran to continue the requested computations.

Can you help me? Or maybe point me towards a "simpler" solution?

As a first trial, I am messing around with [ForPy](https://github.com/ylikx/forpy). I ran successfully some sample scripts in which I am passing arguments from Fortran to Python and the other way around successfully. However, when it comes to couple it with the master code I am working with, I struggle to add the necessary information in the Cmake file when I recompile it to include this modification.

Many thanks,

Comment: At the very least, people will need to know which Fortran compiler you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question is too broad. People cannot help you at this level of vagueness, even if they want to. Please make it more specific. What does CMake have to do with this problem? Is this an open-source library? If yes, then have you sought help from the authors?